# HTML Div/Centering

Tags: css, html, css-float

Hey so first of all I'm terrible with HTML. Div confuses the hell out of me. Now what I am trying to do, I want these two boxes to be centered on the middle of the page with about 20px between them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FirstCSS.css">
<title>Services and Rates</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:pink;">
<div id="top" align="center">
<header>
    <h1 style="color:purple">Services and Rates</h1>

    <nav>
    <hr color="purple" width="80%">
    <table style="color:purple">
    <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqhomepage.html">Home</a></td>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqaboutme.html">About Me</a></td>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqphotogallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></td>
    <td><a href="mqservicesandrates.html">Services and Rates</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr color="purple" width="80%">
    </nav>
    </div>


    <div id="embroideryrates" class="centeredlistleft" >
    <h3 style="color:purple" align="center"> Embroidery </h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Colored Towel (Non White)
    <ul>
    <li>$12</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>White Towel
    <ul>
    <li>$8</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="quiltingrates" class="centeredlistright">
    <h3 style="color:purple" align="center"> Quilting </h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Custom Made Quilt
    <ul>
    <li>$400</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Batting
    <ul>
    <li>$75</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Lessons
    <ul>
    <li> $50/hour</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Right now the two boxes for Embroidery and Quilting are on the far left and right. I just cannot seem to get them centered. And here is my CSS.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.centeredlistleft {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
border:2px solid;
float:left;

}

.centeredlistright {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
border:2px solid;
float:right;

}

.body{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
color: purple;;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm way off here and over complicating things but again the Div tag has never made sense to me and I just cannot seem to get a handle on it.

Comment: So I actually finally figured this out before I came back here to check. There were two things I had wrong or added. First in the CSS for .body I did not hae auto have margin: 0. Secondly I added a div container around both divs and made it class body. Thanks everyone that suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this sample......

change your css with the below css....

```
 .content {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:lavender;
 }
.body{
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 text-align: center;
 color: purple;;
 }
```

for demo :http://jsfiddle.net/ypwjY/

Answer (score 0):

This works. Put a wrapper division for the two lists

```
<div id="listswrapper" >
 <div id="embroideryrates" class="centeredlistleft" >
 <div id="quiltingrates" class="centeredlistright">
</div>
```

Then do the styling as follows:

```
#listswrapper {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;

}

.centeredlistleft {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  border:2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.centeredlistright {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  border:2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Some points noted:**

The solution given by q0re does not work (though I am not the one to downvote :)) due to `float:left` in the centeredlistleft division. Rather, both the lists (divs) should be displayed as inline block.

The solution by SKV might work (I have not tested) due to align="center" but that is a deprecated way of styling.

The solution by Sindhu applies center styling to the whole body. this may not be desirable if you want to control per-division. Also the content div with width 400px is unclear as your two divisions have a combined with of 600px plus border and padding.

**Very important:**
may be you incorrectly copied, but please make sure your HTML is always well formed. I see a missing end-body tag. In general such minor mistakes can (do) lead to time-consuming bugs for beginners.

happy web developing!

Answer (score 0):

check it out [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5szZ8/)

add some css

```
#listboxes {
  width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;

}

.centeredlistleft {

    margin-right:10px;
}

.centeredlistright {

    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use below code for result requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FirstCSS.css">
<title>Services and Rates</title>
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.centeredlistleft {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
border:2px solid;
float:left;

}

.centeredlistright {
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
border:2px solid;
float:right;

}

.body{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
color: purple;;
}
.outerdiv {
    width:635px;
}
.outermost {

}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:pink;">
<div id="top" align="center">
<header>
    <h1 style="color:purple">Services and Rates</h1>

    <nav>
    <hr color="purple" width="80%">
    <table style="color:purple">
    <tr>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqhomepage.html">Home</a></td>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqaboutme.html">About Me</a></td>
    <td style="padding-right: 50px"><a href="mqphotogallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></td>
    <td><a href="mqservicesandrates.html">Services and Rates</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr color="purple" width="80%">
    </nav>
    </div>
<div class="outermost" align="center">
    <div class="outerdiv">
    <div id="embroideryrates" class="centeredlistleft" >
    <h3 style="color:purple" align="center"> Embroidery </h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Colored Towel (Non White)
    <ul>
    <li>$12</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>White Towel
    <ul>
    <li>$8</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="quiltingrates" class="centeredlistright">
    <h3 style="color:purple" align="center"> Quilting </h3>
    <ul>
    <li>Custom Made Quilt
    <ul>
    <li>$400</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Batting
    <ul>
    <li>$75</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Lessons
    <ul>
    <li> $50/hour</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think so, just bcoz you used margin: 0 auto; and i use allign:center.. check your mind.

Comment: Read: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp  --- The <div> align attribute is `not supported` in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

The align attribute of `<div>` is `deprecated` in HTML 4.01.

Comment: `NOT` supported in HTML 4.01? Thanks for downvote and learn to accept the better solution if you have no idea ;-)